# Spring boot: Struggling with validating nested entity - where i need to validate only 1 unique property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a scenario where i need to validate a nested entity one column.
Actually it goes like this. I have a mapping between two entities for example User and Company entities. and i have a foreign key of Company table inside User table. And in my create user form i have a drop down for selecting a company, and when user submits the form only one unique column is send to server where i fetch the company based on that column and set it to incoming user object. Now i'm implementing validation on user table, all the primitive fields are validated well. Now i want to validate if the unique column in nested company object.

Note: I google search it and i found i can put @Valid annotation on top of nested company object, but this way i have to validate mandatory fields for company object. But i only want to validate the unique column which i receive from the create user form.

So, is there any way around this problem. Please help.

Update: I have added the two classes for the current scenario

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long userId;

    @NotEmpty("loginId can't be empty")
    @Column(name="login_id")
    private String loginId;

    @NotEmpty("password can't be empty")
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn( name="company_id")
    private Company company; 

    // getters/setters

}


@Entity
@Table(name="company")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @Column(name="company_id")
    private long companyId;

    @NotEmpty("company short name can't be empty")
    @Column(name="company_short_name")
    private companyShortName; // unique column i want to validate when user form is submitted.

    @NotEmpty("company name can't be empty")
    @Column(name="company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @NotEmpty("company desc can't be empty")
    @Column(name="company_desc")
    private String companyDesc;

    // getters/setters

}
```

Thanks,
Shafqat Shafi.

Comment: Please provide some code samples to go with your question.

Comment: you want to validate if `user.company.id` is unique right ?

Comment: @zakaria amine i want to validate if company shortName is populated when user submits create user form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom validator for `User` implementing `org.springframework.validation.Validator`:

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) target;

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getCompany().getCompanyShortName())) {
            errors.reject("your.error.code");
        }
    }
}
```

Use the validator with initBinder in the controller where your handlers are:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @InitBinder("yourCommandObjectName")    // most probably "user"
    public void init(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(userValidator);
    }

    // handlers
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Surely will try your solution.

Answer (score 2):

As correctly mentioned in others answers I would like to add more to it - you can create more than one CustomValidators for each of your BO or controller using **ServiceLocatorFactoryBean**
I will try to give an idea of how to create multiple custom validators and then use them dynamically at run time by providing its name to the factory method.
Also given an idea of how to check for duplicate records in validation

First at your configuration class define the locator bean,it will internally use BeanFactory.getBean byName to identify your custom validator classes -

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.data.proj")
public class Config {


    @Bean
    public ServiceLocatorFactoryBean serviceLocatorBean(){
        ServiceLocatorFactoryBean bean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setServiceLocatorInterface(MyValidatorFactory.class);
        return bean;
    }
```

}
Now create a CustomValidator interface that will extend spring Validator and it will have all the validation methods that each of your custom validatorImpl will implement -

```
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public interface MyAppValidator extends Validator {
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors);
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors, String companyShrtName);
}
```

Now create a MyValidatorFactory.java intercae that will return your runtime validator bean which has implementation specific to a BO validation  on -passing the bean name

```
public interface MyValidatorFactory {
    public MyAppValidator getValidator(String validatorImplBeanName);
}
```

Next we will implement to Custom Validators for two of our mapped POJO of controllers-
First ValidatorImpl

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class UserValidator extends HibernateDaoSupport implements MyAppValidator{
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) target;
        if (Constants.SAVE.equals(user.action)) {
            validateForUnique(target, errors);
        } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getCompany().getCompanyShortName())) {
            errors.reject("your.error.code");
        }
    }

    // checking for duplicate - giving an overview of your requirement
    public void validateForUnique(Object target, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) target;
        if (errors.getErrorCount() > 0) {
            logger.info("validation resulted in thses many errir" + errors.getErrorCount());
        } else {
            Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Criteria ct = session.createCriteria(User.class, "user");
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user.id", StringUtils.trimToNull(user.id)));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user.shortName", StringUtils.trimToNull(user.shortName)));
            boolean duplicateCheck = criteria.list().size() > 0 ? true : false;
            if (duplicateCheck) {
                errors.rejectValue("shortName", "Already exists", new Object[] {}, "Company short name already exists");
            }
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Second Validator- AccountValidator.java

```
public class AccountValidator  implements MyAppValidator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom(Account.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Account cc = (Account) target;
        if (Constants.SAVE.equals(user.action)) {
            validateForUnique(target, errors);
        } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(cc.getAccNumber())) {
            errors.reject("your.error.code");
        }
    }   
}
```

Now we will identify the validators at runtime and use them using FactoryInterface.
Let say from your controller, you call this UserServiceImpl.java class where you validate your BO received from UserForm
Inside UserServiceImpl.java
package com.example.ServiceLocator;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.MapBindingResult;

public class UserServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    MyValidatorFactory myValidatorFactory;

    public UserVO getUserDetails(UserVO vo) {
        // some processing...

    }

    public UserVo perfromValidation(UserVO vo) {
        Map hm = new HashMap<>();
        MapBindingResult errors = new MapBindingResult(hm, "User project");
        MyAppValidator validator = myValidatorFactory.getValidator("UserValidator");
        validator.validate(vo, errors);
        if (errors != null && errors.getErrorCount() > 0) {
            vo.setValid(false);
            vo.setErrorCode(500); //put your implementation here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. will surely try this out.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I can think of is using manual hibernate validation :

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<Company>> errors = validator.validateProperty(company, "companyShortName");

if (errors.size() > 0) {
//companyShortName is empty
}
```

Comment: Short and simple. Worked for me.